# How do I build a Google Add On with a menu item that pops up in all documents?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script, so forgive me if I use the wrong terminology. I'm trying to build a Google Apps Add-On but I'm having trouble piecing things together. Ideally I'd like to add a right-click menu to all documents when someone installs my Add-On. Similarly to how LucidChart adds a top level menu to all docs.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createAddonMenu() says:

> If the script is running as an add-on, the sub-menu name matches the add-on's name in the web store; if the script is bound to the document directly, the sub-menu name matches the script's name.

Should this work in an Add On:

```js
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem("Test", "test").addToUi()
}

function test() {
  DocumentApp.getUi.alert("Yeah!")
}
```

and if so, what am I supposed to do after doing this to trigger `onOpen` on all the documents I open in my account? I mean, at the moment, just to test this add on (that is, to start developing it). I'm not sure what to do to *run it*.

Comment: Where it says it have to be bound

Comment: It say ` if the script is bound to the document directly,...`, it does not say that it needs to be bound.

Comment: @Kos: I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a unbound/standalone script when creating a addon. But it'll become bound to the document, when a user installs the addon on that document. See [Authorization modes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes).

Comment: Lucidchart gets installed on the account, not a single document, and every time I open any document the menu is there. I'm trying to replicate that.

Comment: @pupeno Yes, but it needs to be used in that  document. Read about 'enabled vs installed'

Comment: When I install the LucidChart add on on my Google account, the menu appears in all documents automatically without me doing anything.

Comment: @pupeno Yes, because it is installed for you. It won't show up for others. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled For the addon to be fully functional, it needs to be installed **and** enabled.

Comment: I've read that, but I still have no idea how to get my code to run.

Comment: @pupeno It'll work.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm literally staring at my code wondering what action I need to do for it to run.

Comment: @pupeno You need to publish it as a addon. Or use "Test as addon" in legacy editor.

Comment: I've been piecing it together, show manifest, add "addOns" to manifest, Test Deployment, still not running though.

Comment: @pup See my previous link,  test as addon > https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons (In editor >top right > Use legacy editor)

Comment: So, is it not possible to develop an add on on the new editor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm piecing together an answer. There are currently two editors for Google Scripts, the current one and the legacy one. I still don't know if it's possible to test an add-on with the current one, but it seems possible in the legacy one.

To switch from the current one to the legacy one, there's a link on the top right:

[image]

Once in the old editor there's "Run" menu:

[image]

that has a "Test as add-on" function:

[image]

That opens a dialog that allows you to open another document with the add-on [installed, enabled, or both](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled):

[image]

Before finding this out, I enabled showing the script manifest, added the "addOn" entry, and deployed as a Test Add On in the new editor. I'm not sure if that had an effect.